# Android split APK or re-packaging?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, apk, build.gradle

I'm developing an Android app with NDK using Android Studio 2.1.

Ideally, I'd have multiple APKs generated when hitting ctrl-F9. One per architecture. But currently I have to hit Build->Build APK. I don't understand why is it not part of the build process.

Even though my app/build.gradle contains a few flavours (one per arch), 'Build APK' is generating only one and it's a pain to go and select a different arch and hit 'Build APK' 7 times :P

So, first question: can I configure AS/gradle to generate APK per arch as part of the build process (ctrl-F9) to avoid the above nuisance?

If not, can I generate a 'all' APK (remove 'productFlavours') and slice it manually?

That is, make 7 copies, and then in each copy remove all but one of the signatures and all but one of the so files.

Answer (score 0):

if you run  `./gradlew assemble` it should build all permutations of your flavors. If you click Edit Configuration in the setting (easiest way it from the dropdown next to the green Play button) you might be able to configure in there as well.